# Bootsrap Navbar not dropping down

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, nav

My bootstrap navbar is not working and I dont know why.  I have copied and pasted the code to my other projects and it works just fine.  I created the navbar using jQuery.  Not sure what I am missing.  The expanded version works fine.  It is just when the navbar is collapsed I am having issues.  When I click the dropdown button, it only highlights the button.  I still need to add some spans and active classes to the navbar but as I said, it works on other projects.

here is my html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script
    src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"
    integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0="
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ygbV9kiqUc6oa4msXn9868pTtWMgiQaeYH7/t7LECLbyPA2x65Kgf80OJFdroafW" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/index.css">
    <script src="../js/navbar.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/index.js"></script>
    <title>Nielsen Consultants</title>
</head>

<body>
        <div class="boot-nav"></div>
        <div class="container"></div>

</body>

</html>
```

and js

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
    let bootNav=$("<nav>")
    bootNav.attr({
        class: "navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light"
    });
    let brandElement=$("<a>");
    brandElement.attr({
        class: "navbar-brand",
        href:"#"});
    brandElement.text("Nielsen Consultants")
    let dropdownBttn=$("<button>");
    dropdownBttn.attr({
        class: "navbar-toggler",
        type: "button",
        "data-toggle": "collapse",
        "data-target": "#navbarNavAltMarkup",
        "aria-controls": "navbarNavAltMarkup",
        "aria-expanded":"false",
        "aria-label":"Toggle navigation"
    })
    let dropdownIcon=$("<span>");
    dropdownIcon.attr({
        class:"navbar-toggler-icon"
    });
    dropdownBttn.append(dropdownIcon);
    let navCollapse=$("<div>");
    navCollapse.attr({
        class: "collapse navbar-collapse",
        id: "navbarNavAltMarkup"
    })
    let navItems=$("<div>");
    navItems.attr({
        class:"navbar-nav"
    });
    let navAbout = $("<a>");
    navAbout.attr({
        class: "nav-item nav-link",
        href: "#",
    })
    navAbout.text("About")
    let navContact = $("<a>");
    navContact.attr({
        class: "nav-item nav-link",
        href: "#",
    })
    navContact.text("Contact");
    navItems.append(navAbout,navContact);
    navCollapse.append(navItems);
    bootNav.append(brandElement,dropdownBttn,navCollapse);
    $(".boot-nav").append(bootNav);
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Please maintain proper order for your script tags as below

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">

 <head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384- 
    TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/index.css">
   <script src="../js/navbar.js"></script>
   <script src="../js/index.js"></script>
   <title>Nielsen Consultants</title>
 </head>

 <body>
   <div class="boot-nav"></div>
   <div class="container"></div>


   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"
     integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous">
   </script>
   <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
     integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous">
   </script>
   <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
     integrity="sha384-w1Q4orYjBQndcko6MimVbzY0tgp4pWB4lZ7lr30WKz0vr/aWKhXdBNmNb5D92v7s" crossorigin="anonymous">
   </script>
 </body>

 </html>
```

Comment: This is for bootstrap v4.5

Comment: Awesome, had to move the jquery back at the top but that fixed it, you rock.  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Before it, can i know what kind of bootstrap version that you used joe ?

Comment: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/

Comment: I think 4.0, copied the bar from this page

Comment: You can ask question on comments.

Comment: look at you css bootstrap linkrel, it direct to bootstrap 5.